# Skipping certain characters

Tags: c, input, character, output

I have created a program in C that will read the contents of a file, then output it into a new file. However, I need to extend this program to skip HTML tags. Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I'm supposed to do or how I should do it?

All I know how to do is to skip characters separately, but how do I skip so it inclusively skips everything in the "< and >"?

If possible, please don't give me an entire completed code, because this is homework and I want to learn from it.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a flag which indicates if you need to keep symbol or not. Change it from true to false if character=="<" and back if ">".

Comment: The only truly correct answer is "use an HTML parser".  Any solution complex enough to navigate the corner cases reliably is going to be more trouble than it's worth, and you'll basically just have the hard half of an HTML parser by the time it's done anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you set up a flag (call it `html_flag`) and set it to 0 (`false`).  You can do this by declaring it as an `int`.  As you go over each character, you output everything if `html_flag` is `0`, till you hit the `<` character.  At that point, you set `html_flag` to 1.  You do not output any scanned characters if the flag is a 1.  You turn the flag back to `0` when you encounter the `>` character, and continue doing this over the entire file.

Comment: Breaks on `<img alt=">">`.

Answer (score 0):

While you are reading your file, you can setup a flag when you find a '<' char, and down that flag when you find a '>'.

When this flag is up, you just ignore and read the next character.

The only problem i can think of is in case of your HTML has something like this:

```
<a href="something with '>'">
```

In that case, you will need another flag for "".

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean flag which indicates if you need to keep symbol or not.

Pseudocode:

```
tag = false
for(ch in text){
    if(ch == "<")
        tag = true
    if not tag
        print ch
    if(ch == ">")
        tag = false
}
```